# Suddenly my software & update app does not stop refreshing the cache

Tags: command-line, update-manager, 20.10

My software & update app does not stop refreshing the cache. It is so frustrating. What should I do? I even tried forcing quit the application. It will not quit. I am using ubuntu 20.10. I install my updates and try again. Nothing works. I have to install my updates from cmd (command) line now because the software updater app will not let me do anything on it.

Comment: Never mind. I rebooted my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted my computer and it worked.